# Why does RadEditor interpret the html content?

Tags: c#, telerik, radeditor

I use Telerik Rad Editor  which is below in an asp.net content management panel

```
<telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditorSummary" runat="server" ToolsFile="~/RadEditorTools.xml" Height="150"></telerik:RadEditor>
```

When I write below statement as a content:

`<html><body></body><br/><img alt="" src="" /></html>`

and insert it to the database, it seems the same like 
`<html><body></body><br/><img alt="" src="" /></html>`. (I look it from SQL Management Studio)

But when I open that record to edit again from asp.net panel, RadEditorSummary shows it like `<html><body></body><br><img alt="" src="" ></html>` 
it prevent to show `/` in `br` and `img` tags.

How can stop that operation?

Edit: for image tag and br tag are everything ok.
but 
when I write `<xsl:key name="cat1" match="/NewDataSet/Cat1/text()" use="." />` it shows `<xsl:key name="cat1" match="/NewDataSet/Cat1/text()" use="." >`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can experience this problem if you have disabled the ConvertToXhtml filter of RadEditor. It is enabled by default and ensures that the produced content is XHTML.

You can test the filter in this live demo: 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/builtincontentfilters/defaultcs.aspx